# Remove all commas from a string in C# 3

Tags: c#, string, replace, c#-3.0

i have a string type variable like `a="a,b,c,d";`I want to remove all commas and get new value for a like `abcd`.I tried `a.Replace(",","")` but it is not working.I am using c# 3.0

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this instead

```
a = a.Replace("," , "");
```

**Edit**

Your code is correct as far as using Replace() function goes. What you are missing is that Replace() does not modify the original string, it returns a new (updated) string which you should save.

Answer (score 3):

```
a.Replace(",", "");
```

Works for me, your problem lays else where.
Also try this:

```
= String.Concat(a.Split(','));
```